# Requests from referer <empty> are blocked."

Tags: laravel, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Requests from referer "" are blocked."
I'm using YouTube API v3 search in my laravel application.

```
$params = array(
            "part" => "snippet",
            "q" => $term,
            "type" => "channel",
            "maxResults" => $limit,
            "key" => env('YOUTUBE_KEY')
        );
        $curl_session = curl_init();
        $curl_options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?'. http_build_query($params),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl_session, $curl_options);

        $response = curl_exec($curl_session);

        curl_close($curl_session);

        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        return $response;
```

The search should work as expected.

Comment: The given YouTube Data API v3 key requires a given referer to authenticate its user.

Comment: What would be the referer value @BenjaminLoison ?
This code works on Local but not work in production server.

Comment: I tried adding the referer as my main site domain eg: `https://example.com` but not worked